# How to call internal functions in route module (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, function, methods, express, routes

I'm using node.js w/ express.js, and have following lines inside ./route/users.js:

```
exports.add = function(req, res) {
   // some code here
    this.list();
}

exports.delete = function(req, res) {
    // some code here
    this.list();
}


exports.list = function(req, res) {
    // some code here
}
```

Problem is that this.list() doesn't work, what I get is this error: TypeError: Object # has no method 'list'

I've tried different approach too:

```
module.exports = {
  add: function(req, res) {
    // some code here
    this.list();
  },

  delete: function(req, res) {
    // some code here
    this.list();
  },

  list: function(req, res) {
    // some code here
    this.list();
  }
}
```

But didn't worked too.. Btw, if we ignore that error with list() calls, which one is correct way of writing routes?

Answer (score 0):

One options is to define and refer to `list` as a local, then export it. Also note that you'll probably want to pass `req` and `res` when calling `list()`.

```
function list(req, res) {
  // ...
}

module.exports = {
  add: function add(req, res) {
    // ...
    list(req, res);
  },

  delete: function (req, res) {
    // ...
    list(req, res);
  },

  list: list
};
```

The problem with using `this` is it's not tied to the `exports` object. The value of `this` within any given `function` depends on [how that function was called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) rather than how it was defined.